# The NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 'persist' across app updates?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I know it should persist if my Core Data Model has not changed, but how safe it is ?

I'm an inhouse developer and we have 20 iPods with some information there, entered by our users. Now there's some bug that this info can't be exported, so we have to install a new update and export that information.

We are not going to change the Core Data Model, just some routines for export, so the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator should be the same ...

We are going to pack the app and install the updates from iTunes, this will be ok and the data will be there ?????

thanks,

r.

### edit:

so, the iPods were synchronaized with other iTunes, now if I want to update the app that it's there, iTunes says that is going to delete ALL applications and their DATA, and the computer that installed them is not working now ...

so , how I can install a corrected version without losing the data ?????

thanks!

r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have followed practice shown in template generated iPhone apps and copied (or created) your data in the apps Documents folder - then yes, it will still be there when you update from the App Store.